# Issue using Ubuntu Gitlab Runner

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

`Gitlab-runner version: 10.1.0`
`Ubuntu: 16.04`

**Installed runner:**

I've installed the runner as per the [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#installing-the-runner) and registered the runner as per the [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html) again.

**Issue**

So the runner accepts the first, one or two jobs within 5 minutes of it being active, then after that time, all jobs are pending on that runner.

`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "ubuntu-test-runner"
  url = "edited-out"
  token = "edited-out"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

Running `sudo service gitlab-runner status` gives:

```
gitlab-runner.service - GitLab Runner
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-11-09 10:59:44 GMT; 24min ago
 Main PID: 7156 (gitlab-runner)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gitlab-runner.service
           └─7156 /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner

Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7343]: + ??? root:gitlab-runner
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7343]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user gitlab-runner by (uid=0)
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7348]: Successful su for gitlab-runner by root
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7348]: + ??? root:gitlab-runner
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7348]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user gitlab-runner by (uid=0)
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7352]: Successful su for gitlab-runner by root
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7352]: + ??? root:gitlab-runner
Nov 09 11:00:12 su[7352]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user gitlab-runner by (uid=0)
Nov 09 11:00:44 gitlab-runner[7156]: time="2017-11-09T11:00:44Z" level=warning msg="Appending trace to coordinator aborted" code=202 job=765 job-log=0-846 job-status=canceled runner=28fdac52 sent-log=846-846 status="202 Accepted" 
                                                                             <nil>
Nov 09 11:00:44 gitlab-runner[7156]: time="2017-11-09T11:00:44Z" level=warning msg="Appending trace to coordinator aborted" code=202 job=765 job-log=0-846 job-status=canceled runner=28fdac52 sent-log=846-846 status="202 Accepted"
```

So the runner service is active and running (accepted the first job), but doesn't seem to be accepting any more jobs and leaving everything at pending.

I can also see the runner in `/runners/admin` on the website, but the last contact just keeps going up and doesn't reset.

If I run `sudo gitlab-runner restart` it picks up the job again, but then stops accepting jobs after that first one.

Is there any other ways I can debug why the runner isn't accepting any more jobs? Or if anyone knows what the issue is I'm having?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is;

Stop your runner (`gitlab-runner stop`) and then run attached with the [debug flag](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/faq/README.md#run-in-debug-mode) so you can see everything it does:

`gitlab-runner --debug run`

And start feeding it jobs.

Comment: Running `sudo gitlab-runner run` (or with debug flag) always works though. It always manages to pick up the job. I'm trying to get it to work as a service but it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Could this be something to do with permissions perhaps?